# Symbolic verification of the analytical equation using Mathematica

Tags: linear-algebra, symbolic

The matrices A, B are companion matrices of the form $A = \left[C_{1}\middle|\frac{I}{0\dots0}\right], B= \left[C_{2}\middle|\frac{I}{0\dots0}\right]$
[image]

I was thinking
a) if we can verify equation (2), (3) using Mathematica?
b) Implementing a Schur complement using Mathematica
c) use Mathematica to consider other cases of $n$ (when $n$ is not a multiple of $3$).

[image]

Comment: You'd be happy with verifying for finitely many `n` (say up to $999$) or you want to verify this keeping `n` symbolic throughout? Also, what have you tried so far, and please include your Mathematica code.

Comment: Thanks, I just want  to see the patterns I get from Mathematica match (2), (3) as per analytics for large $n$ (yes 999 sounds good). I have not used Mathematica much but have known that it is nice for symbolics..I was searching for Schur complement in Mathematica but could not find much hits..

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with alphas and betas. E.g. for n==6 the highest index,, alphas and betas contain indices higher than n

Comment: Oh ok, I think using Mathematica, a correct generalized expression could be derived by looking into the patterns as different values of $n$ are considered?

Comment: Please address @DanielHuber's observation. Concerning [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), it is not difficult to program this oneself, for example `schurDet[mat_,ind_] := With[{n=Length[mat]},With[{rest=Complement[Range[1,n],ind]}, With[{A=mat[[ind,ind]], B=mat[[ind,rest]], C=mat[[rest,ind]], D=mat[[rest,rest]]}, Det[A]*Det[D-C.Inverse[A].B]]]]; schurDetFirstLast[mat_]:=schurDet[mat,{1,Length[mat]}];`. For example, `RandomReal[{-1,1},{9,9}]//{Det[#],schurDetFirstLast[#]}&`.

Comment: Yes, something wrong with the alpha and beta. They generate b and a with higher index that in the matrices. So it can not be correct. I just coded it and it does not verify because of this.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJjbq.png)

Comment: @Nasser please see your last expression of $\det(AB+ A + I)$. You have entered it wrongly as $\det(AB + B + I)$

Comment: I took screen shot in the middle of trying things. I thought may be book had typo, so I changed A to B to try and then took screen shot. I forgot I changed it. But  here is updating screen shot. Still does not verify.   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYCxE.png)  There is something wrong or typo in the book.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what the correct equation would be instead? can Mathematica provide a hint in this?

Comment: @DanielHuber I think in $a_{i}$ if $i > 6$, then we need to consider $a_{i(mod 6)}$..

Comment: This produces a0

Comment: Right, I just checked carefully and found a. Mistake: the summation in eqn (3) runs from k=0 to n/3  - 1 and not from k=0 to n/3.. And it seems it does not cross the maximum index of a_i's..

Comment: **runs from k=0 to n/3 - 1**  Nope. It still does not verify.  I just checked. There is still something else wrong.

Comment: See my edit question, seems like it is giving equality between two determinants

Comment: I do not understand what you wrote. What does `KroneckerDelta[j - 3]` is supposed to be? This will give zero all the time. That is not what the book says to so. $\delta_{3,i}$ is not the same as $\delta_{3-i}$. You need to change the code to `KroneckerDelta[3, j]` to make it match. Also I do not know what `ID` is. And you did not show the A and B matrices.  But if you think you found the correct solution, you could always answer your own question,. But please post inputForm code and not images.

Comment: Please see the edit question..I am facing some issue to post the code in format

Answer (score 4):

For n  a multiple of 3, this is right, but for other n, it is wrong:

```
n = 6;
aa = Table[
   Which[j == 1, Subscript[a, i], j == i + 1, 1, True, 0], {i,n}, {j,n}];
bb = Table[
   Which[j == 1, Subscript[b, i], j == i + 1, 1, True, 0], {i,n}, {j,n}];
al[i_] = - KroneckerDelta[3, i] + Sum[Subscript[a, 3 k + i], {k, 0, n/3 - 1}];
be[i_] = - KroneckerDelta[3, i] + Sum[Subscript[b, 3 k + i], {k, 0, n/3 - 1}];
Det[aa . bb + aa + IdentityMatrix[n]] ==
  Det[{{al[1] - al[3], be[1] - be[2]}, {al[2] - al[3], be[1] - be[3]}}] ==
  Det[{{al[1], 1, be[2]}, {al[2], 1, be[3]}, {al[3], 1, be[1]}}] // Expand

(* True *)
```

But for e.g. n==5 this returns False. This seems understandable as 3 appears explicit in the equations.

Comment: Yes actually I want to see what other changes in the equations so that it works for other $n$.. so that all $n \in \Bbb{N}$ can be covered? and I was thinking to see a Schur implementation in code format which i dont know

Answer (score 4):

Here is a verification for n (even) up to 100. It does not verify for all n.

[image]

I verifies for values that are 3*n. So `6,12,18,24,30,36,42,...`

### code

```
ClearAll[n, a, b];
makeMatrix[(n_Integer)?Positive, v_Symbol] := Module[{t},
   t = DiagonalMatrix[Table[1, {n - 1}]];
   t = Join[t, {Table[0, {n - 1}]}];
   t = Join[List /@ Array[v, n], t, 2]
   ];
alpha[(i_Integer)?Positive, (n_Integer)?Positive] := -KroneckerDelta[3, i] + 
   Sum[a[3*k + i], {k, 0, n/3 - 1}];
beta[(i_Integer)?Positive, (n_Integer)?Positive] := -KroneckerDelta[3, i] + 
   Sum[b[3*k + i], {k, 0, n/3 - 1}];

Manipulate[Module[{A, B, mat1, mat2},
  A = makeMatrix[n, a];
  B = makeMatrix[n, b];
  mat1 = {{alpha[1, n] - alpha[3, n], 
     beta[1, n] - beta[2, n]}, {alpha[2, n] - alpha[3, n], 
     beta[1, n] - beta[3, n]}};
  mat2 = {{alpha[1, n], 1, beta[2, n]}, {alpha[2, n], 1, 
     beta[3, n]}, {alpha[3, n], 1, beta[1, n]}};

  If[Simplify[Det[A . B + A + IdentityMatrix[n]] === Det[mat1]], 
   Row[{"Verified for n=", n}], Row[{"Not Verified for n=", n}]]
  ]
 ,
 {{n, 6, "n"}, 2, 100, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {n}
 ]
```